# Eclipse package names instead of imports

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

How to configure Eclipse to always use fully qualified names instead of automatically adding imports ?

i.e. if you are using `Foo`, Eclipse does an import of `com.stackoverflow.Foo;` I would like it to always write com.stackoverflow.Foo when Foo is used.

Please don't ask why. :)

Answer (score 9):

in Panel `Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Content Assist`

uncheck "Add import instead of qualified name"